# TornadoFX not finding JavaFx

Tags: java, tornadofx

I'm trying my first first app with [TornadoFx](https://tornadofx.io/), so I started with this code:

```
package no.tornado.fxsample.workspace

import javafx.application.Application
import tornadofx.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) = launch<MyApp>(args)

class MyApp: App(MyView::class)

class MyView: View() {
    override val root = VBox()
    init {
        with(root) {
        this += Button("Press Me")
        this += Label("Waiting")
        }
    }
}
```

but apparently it is full of errors, and not able to find JavaFX

My `gradle.build` is:

```
// set up the kotlin-gradle plugin
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.60'
    repositories {
       mavenLocal()    //    mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

// apply the kotlin-gradle plugin
apply plugin: "kotlin"

// add kotlin-stdlib dependencies.
repositories {
    mavenLocal()  // mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    //dependencies from a remote repositor
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    compile "no.tornado:tornadofx:1.7.12"
}

jar {
    manifest {
        //Define mainClassName as: '[your_namespace].[your_arctifact]Kt'
        attributes ('Main-Class': 'MyAppKt', "Implementation-Title": "Gradle",
                   "Implementation-Version": 1)
    }
    // NEW LINE HERE !!!
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}

sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs += 'src/kotlin'
    main.resources.srcDirs += 'src/resources'
}

kotlin {
    experimental.coroutines 'enable'
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget= 1.8  // optional, Minimum jvmTarget of 1.8 needed since Kotlin 1.1
    kotlinOptions.suppressWarnings = true
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to [this](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-javafx-hello-world/blob/master/build.gradle) It worked with Intellij Idea by adding this plugin:

```
apply from: "http://dl.bintray.com/content/shemnon/javafx-gradle/8.1.1/javafx.plugin"
```

Unfortunately this plugin is [not maintained any more](https://bitbucket.org/shemnon/javafx-gradle/issues/47/adding-manifest-attribute-javafx#comment-24360784) :(

More strange also, is this code required only once, it can be deleted after that, without having any error, may be it is cashed somewhere!!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you're using OpenJDK, which doesn't have JavaFX by default? I highly recommend that you install Oracle JDK 8.

Your code is using some heavily outdated syntax. As you're a new user, I suspect we have some outdated code samples lying around - could you tell me where you found these examples?

This is how it should be written now:

```
class MyView : View() {
    override val root = vbox {
        button("Press me")
        label("Waiting")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Edvin, actually I'm using latest ORACLE `JDK 1.8.0_144`, I got it fixed my got another error now, `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics
 at myApp.MainKt.main(main.kt)`

Comment: Good :) According to your screenshot, your code is also in the wrong package, and is called `MyAppKt`, not `MainKt. In any case, install the TornadoFX plugin and simply click the Tornado gutter icon next to your App instance to run the app. It will set it up correctly for you.

Comment: Thanks, I really do not yet understand what happened and why, now the app is working fine with me when I use command line with MS VS Code, but when I use Intellej IDEA still getting errors?!

Comment: I posted what I got using command line vs what I got using intellij Idea as an answer instead of updating my question, kindly have a look. thanks

Comment: I got the old code from: https://edvin.gitbooks.io/tornadofx-guide/content/part1/3.%20Components.html

Comment: It is explained that this is not the way to do it :) It's just to let you understand what goes on behind the covers when you use the builders :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I jumped directly to the code without reading the text :)

Comment: I'm glad you brought it up, I'll update the guide to only show best practices :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternate option, I just wrote it as answer in case some one interested about it.
The below code is now running with me using `command line` with `MS VS Code`:

`main.kt`:

```
import javafx.*
import javafx.application.Application
import javafx.scene.control.Button
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox
import tornadofx.*
import javafx.scene.control.Label

class MyApp: App(MyView::class)

class MyView : View() {
    override val root = vbox {
        button("Press me")
        label("Waiting")
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Application.launch(MyApp::class.java, *args)
}
```

`build.gradle`:

```
// set up the kotlin-gradle plugin
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.60'
    repositories {
       mavenLocal()    //    mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

// apply the kotlin-gradle plugin
apply plugin: "kotlin"

// add kotlin-stdlib dependencies.
repositories {
    mavenLocal()  // mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    //dependencies from a remote repositor
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    compile "no.tornado:tornadofx:1.7.12"
}


jar {
    manifest {
        //Define mainClassName as: '[your_namespace].[your_arctifact]Kt'
        attributes ('Main-Class': 'MainKt', "Implementation-Title": "Gradle",
                   "Implementation-Version": 1)
    }
    // NEW LINE HERE !!!
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}


sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs += 'src/kotlin'
    main.resources.srcDirs += 'src/resources'
}

kotlin {
    experimental.coroutines 'enable'
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget= 1.8  // optional, Minimum jvmTarget of 1.8 needed since Kotlin 1.1
    kotlinOptions.suppressWarnings = true
}
```

The output is:
[image]

But at Intellij IDEA still full of errors as below:
[image]

Comment: On intellij you *probably* need to go to `Files > Project structure` and the dialog under`SDK location` item, unselect the `Use embedded JDK` and point to your installed JDK that has the javafx

Answer (score 0):

ver gradle 6.4
ver kotlin 1.3.72
ver tornadofx 1.7.20
ver JDK 14

build.gradle add

```
plugins {
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
}
javafx {
    version = "14"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]
}
```

Comment: could you please provide some context, about what you've done, so others and the questioner could provide from your answer?